# concourse secret sharing does not fully define how to configure vault

Tags: concourse, hashicorp-vault

i am following the instructions [here](http://concourse.ci/creds.html) for how to configure vault for sharing secrets.

ultimately i just want to get my bot's creds to git resources.

i am deploying via docker compose, and have successfully added a vault server to compose.

- where do i run the `concourse atc` commands?  `atc` is not a valid command off of the `concourse` binary found in the `concourse/concourse` images
- can get away from needing this separate secret service entirely if i just put some creds in a file on my box somewhere?  if not, can i run it over http vs https? its all in a trusted environment already

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that! It looks like our documentation was incorrect.

Those should all say

`concourse web --vault-url ...`

If you're running via docker-compose then you should set the appropriate environment variables in your web instance, e.g. `$CONCOURSE_VAULT_URL` or `$CONCOURSE_VAULT_CLIENT_TOKEN`.

If you ever need to know what parameters can be configured, you can always run `docker run concourse/concourse web --help` or `docker run concourse/concourse worker --help`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a boilerplate we pre-configured vault support at https://github.com/EugenMayer/concourseci-server-boilerplate the most interesting part on how to setup vault support is part of the configurator

https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-image-concourse-configurator/blob/master/bin/vault_init.sh

and since client-cert auth is used, also https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-image-concourse-configurator/blob/master/bin/vault_client_cert.sh

You see proper examples on how to store values at https://github.com/EugenMayer/concourseci-server-boilerplate/blob/master/run_vault_test.sh

I am aware, i am linking external sources here, but this topic is way to broad to be answered inline. I posted this just as a reference for anybody looking for further examples - since i did not find a single one for myself